# dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, debconf

In an ansible (ver. 2.10) playbook I would need to invoke the dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server command to recreate SSH server keys.

```
- name: Create new SSH host's keys
  shell: dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
  notify: restart sshd
```

The problem is that dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server opens a dialog box, and the script get stucked...

Looking into ansible documentation, it seems that dpkg-reconfigure can be managed by debconf module:

Code example related to locales module:

```
- name: Set default locale to fr_FR.UTF-8
  debconf:
    name: locales
    question: locales/default_environment_locale
    value: fr_FR.UTF-8
    vtype: select
```

The question from openssh-server debconf module is: What do you want to do about modified configuration file sshd_config? and the answer would be: keep the local version currently installed.

How could I manage it using ansible debconf module?

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `debconf` issue. The file is marked as a config file by Debian packaging and `dpkg` is handling it at a generic level. `dpkg --configure` has `--force-confold` but `dpkg-reconfigure` does not.

https://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; Yes, use Ansible debconf but `mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.config` file aside whilst reconfiguring.

The rest of this is for others searching for insight into debconf and Ansible's debconf module.

I spent some time digging into this and have submitted some docs to the Ansible debconf module which I've edited a bit for this answer.

Reconfiguring packages in Debian using `debconf` is not straightforward!

The Ansible debconf module does not reconfigure packages, it just updates the debconf database. An additional playbook step is needed (typically via notify if debconf makes a change) to reconfigure the package and apply the changes.

Now `debconf` is primarily used for pre-seeding configuration prior to installation.

So, whilst `dpkg-reconfigure` does use debconf data, it is not always authoritative and you may need to check how your package is handled.

`dpkg-reconfigure` is a 3-phase process. It invokes the control scripts from the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory with the following arguments:

```
  <package>.prerm  reconfigure <version>
  <package>.config reconfigure <version>
  <package>.postinst control <version>
```

The main issue is that the `<package>.config` reconfigure step for many packages will first reset the debconf database (overriding changes made by the Ansible module) by checking the on-disk configuration. If this is the case for your package then `dpkg-reconfigure` will effectively ignore changes made by this `debconf` module.

However although `dpkg-reconfigure` finally invokes:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst configure <version>
```

to actually configure the package; using this turns out not to be that simple. The script is expected to be run from a "debconf frontend" and uses IPC to respond to the `_db_cmd` statements in the script.

To see this in more detail

```
export DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=<package>
export DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=<script path>
export DEBIAN_HAS_FRONTEND=1
```

and run the script. I was trying to setup unattended-upgrades so I ran:

```
sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

This then halts waiting for a response from the frontend.

Running

```
/usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

works... but has the exact same problem as `dpkg-reconfigure` - it resets the debconf database :(

This is because running

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

`source`s `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule` which exec()s `/usr/share/debconf/frontend` which forces the `<package>.config` configure phase to take place.

This is done based on the existence (ie using shell [-e])  of the .config file and cannot be avoided.

The solution is to `mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.config` out of the way whilst `dpkg-reconfigure` (or other related debconf code) runs.

Note the Debian programmers manual says that the config script's **sole purpose** is to populate debconf and must not affect other files; so doing this in a playbook is (to my understanding) compliant with debian policy: http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html#AEN113

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and I want to share my workaround.
In my case, I want non-root users to be able to sniff network traffic with wireshark/tshark. The package in question is wireshark-common which I normally reconfigure to modify dumpcap as setuid.

In my playbook, I do the following. First, use debconf to modify the config and than run the dpkg-reconfigure command in non-interactive mode, but only if the config has changed.

```
- name: wireshark setuid
  ansible.builtin.debconf:
    name: wireshark-common
    question: wireshark-common/install-setuid
    value: yes
    vtype: boolean
  register: reconfigure_changed
- name: make debconf changes active
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: "dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common"
  environment:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive
  when: reconfigure_changed.changed
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking myself for a solution but I haven't found one yet to achieve that with debconf and ansible.
The Problem is, debconf has no "selection" in terms of sshd_config.
When you look for debconf and preseed (Debian unattended installation) there is simply no Argument where you can specify to keep the current sshd_config.

for example active debconf settings:

```
  sudo debconf-show openssh-server  
  openssh-server/permit-root-login: false
  openssh-server/password-authentication: false
```

These are the questions for the ansible debconf module.

what we are looking for, but thats not possible:

```
- debconf:
    name: openssh-server
    question: openssh-server/keep-current-sshd-config
    value: true
```

Unfortunately, we have to find a workaround.
For my case, I wanted to reconfigure openssh-server on my raspberry pi's
Luckily, there is a systemd file on raspbian OS /lib/systemd/system/regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service that does what the name says.
To make use of it, just delete the ssh_host_* files and reboot the machine.

If you need to get that for different hosts, you need to find another workaround. Maybe importing new ssh_host key files via ansible, or build a small script.