# Ansible with dpkg-reconfigure command

Tags: ansible, dpkg, slapd

How to write Ansible YAML for tasks done using `dpkg-reconfigure` command that ask question during the process?

**Example**

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

I was trying to write an Ansible playbook to automate reconfiguring `slapd` with default values.

Comment: Hi Kakuye welcome to SO. This site is no a consultancy, it is to help you solve your own problems. Your question does not show any effort, which is why your question is at risk of closure. Having said that, are you sure [`debconf:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/debconf_module.html#examples) isn't what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ansible is mainly a [Configuration Management](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) Tool with which one declared a Desired State, a [Version Control System should be used in general](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/10-great-ansible-practices), a non-interactive approach should be the main goal and any interaction should be prevented.

To do so, the within the comments mentioned [`debconf` module – Configure a .deb package](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/debconf_module.html) could come in place and which can then be used like in [How do I make Ansible actually compile a config file having changed my `debconf` settings for an application?](https://serverfault.com/a/701632/448950).

**Further Similar Q&A**

- [`dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870818/6771046)
- [How to do `dpkg-reconfigure dash` as `bash` automatically?](https://superuser.com/a/1669306/754490)
- [Feeding input values to `dpkg-reconfigure` in a non-interactive way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96215/)